# Placing references with hyperlinks on abstract

Tags: overleaf, back-referencing

I am working on a paper that is a follow-up from another one I have co-authored. Thus, I must insert my previous work on the abstract with a direct link to the first publication. How can I do this on LaTex in Overleaf?

An example of what I want can be seen in the abstract of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.224103), where the authors placed three citations with hyperlinks. I would like to do the same.

Comment: A lot depends on the document class, which is usually provided by the journal in question.  \href from hyperref provides links to other documents on the web.

Comment: The hyperlinks in that paper that you references are inserted by the journal. (Compare with the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06052).) The reason that the journal did so (replaced numbered citations to full hyperlinks) is so that the abstract can stand alone without needing the casual browser to open up the article to see what the citations are pointing at. If you are preparing a manuscript for publication, I would say just let the publisher worry about this. Otherwise, you should use `\href` as John Kormylo suggested.